# Database not setting

Tags: php, mysqli

Pretty much, this isn't inserting anything into the database, and it's really getting to me, I should be, but it's not. Any ideas?
I can't seem to figure it out, I've removed the comma after the last variable too! I don't understand. I may not be the best with php or mysqli but I can handle myself pretty well, and this isn't going to well.

```
 <?php

// <!- Session Check -!> \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
    require("common.php");
                                                       //
                                                       //  
    if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
    {
                                                       //  
        header("Location: index.html");
                                                       //  
        die("Redirecting to index.html");
    }
                                                        //  
// <!- Session Check End -!> /////////////////////////////


// <!- Sanatizing Steps Begin -!> \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
                                                                                 //
                                                                                 //                                                                
// Function to turn single quotes and forward slashes to html characters \\
function quote2entities($string,$entities_type='number')
{
    $search                     = array("\"","'");
    $replace_by_entities_name   = array("&quot;","&apos;");
    $replace_by_entities_number = array("&#34;","&#39;");
    $do = null;
    if ($entities_type == 'number')
    {
        $do = str_replace($search,$replace_by_entities_number,$string);          //
    }
    else if ($entities_type == 'name')
    {
        $do = str_replace($search,$replace_by_entities_name,$string);
    }
    else
    {
        $do = addslashes($string);
    }
    return $do;
}
                                                                                 //    
                                                                                 //
                                                                                 //
                                                                                 //
// Declaring Modifying values \\
$url = $_POST['url'];
 $c = $_POST['company'];
  $cp = $_POST['companyproduct'];
   $curl = $_POST['curl'];
    $mem = $_POST['mem'];
     $model = $_POST['model'];
      $serial = $_POST['serialalgo'];
       $method = $_POST['meth'];
        $warn = $_POST['warn'];
//                                                                               //      
// Declaring original Values for the 3rd Sanatization Step \\
$ourl = $_POST['url'];
 $oc = $_POST['company'];
  $ocp = $_POST['companyproduct'];
   $ocurl = $_POST['curl'];
    $omem = $_POST['mem'];
     $omodel = $_POST['model'];
      $oserial = $_POST['serialalgo'];
       $omethod = $_POST['meth'];
        $owarn = $_POST['warn'];

                                                                                 //
                                                                                 //
                                                                                 //
                                                                                 //
                                                                                 //
            // Input Sanatize 1 of 3 \\
    filter_input(INPUT_GET, $c, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    filter_input(INPUT_GET, $mem, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    filter_input(INPUT_GET, $url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    filter_input(INPUT_GET, $cp, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    filter_input(INPUT_GET, $curl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    filter_input(INPUT_GET, $model, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    filter_input(INPUT_GET, $serial, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    filter_input(INPUT_GET, $warn, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    filter_input(INPUT_GET, $method, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
                                                                                 //
                                                                                 //
                                                                                 //
                                                                                 //
                                                                                 //
// Input Sanatize 2 of 3 \\
//if($oc != $c | $omem != $mem | $ocp != $cp )
//{                                                                              //
//    Echo "Banning Account.";
//header(location: "http://cuntusa.com/");
//Die();
//}
                                                                                 //
                                                                                 //
// Input Sanatize Final of 3 \\
$c = quote2entities($c);
$mem = quote2entities($mem);
$cp = quote2entities($cp);
$curl = quote2entities($curl);
$warn = quote2entities($warn);
$method = quote2entities($method);
$url = quote2entities($url);
$model = quote2entities($model);
$serial = quote2entities($serial);
$date = date("Y-m-d  H:i:s");
$postedby = $_SESSION['user']['username'];
        echo $warn;
        echo $serial;
                                                                                 //
                                                                                 //
                                                                                 //
///////// <!- Santizing Ends -!> //////////////////////////////////////////////////




////////////<!- SQLi Begin -!> \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
//                                                                                                             ////
//                                                                                                             ////
//                                                                                                             ////
// Declaring Resource connection Attributes \\
$username = "=";
$password = "m=";
$host = "=rce.com";
$dbname = "=";
//                                                                                                             ////
//                                                                                                             ////
// Declaring a connection Varible for faster call downs. \\
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname) or die('Error->' .mysqli_error($con));
//                                                                                                             ////
//                                                                                                             ////
// Checking for any errors \\
echo mysqli_error($con);
//                                                                                                             ////
//                                                                                                             ////
// Loading into the database \\
echo $date;
echo $c ;
$query = "INSERT INTO project (company,published,user,contacturl,model,serialalgo,members,method,warn) VALUES (
   '".$c."',
   '".$date."',
   '".$postedby."',
   '".$curl."',
   '".$model."',
   '".$serial."',
   '".$mem."',
   '".$method."',
   '".$warn."',
   )";
mysqli_query($con, $query);
//                                                                                                             ////
//                                                                                                             ////
// Closing the connection \\
mysqli_close($con);
//                                                                                                             ////
//                                                                                                             ////
// <!- End SQLi -!> ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



?>
<!---<html>
<body>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=ht=php">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Dude, this wall of code is *scary*. No wonder it doesn't work. I scrolled a lot but was unable to get to any sensible code

Comment: You should do yourself a favour and switch to prepared statements.

Comment: change your `mysqli_query($con, $query);` to `mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));`

Comment: And you should get rid of the comma at the end of `'".$warn."',`

Comment: The only thing I can get out of this is the last comma in `'".$warn."',` - yet OP states *"I've removed the comma after the last variable too"*

Comment: Yeaup I've removed it, and still nothing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Right, so the code posted is not the code that is causing the problem. Confusing...

Comment: `$url = $_POST['url'];` and `$ourl = $_POST['url'];` etc. ? Giving up right here. Good luck, you'll need it.

Comment: Add some error handling.

Comment: @jeroen Indeed and very confusing, we wrote the same thing at almost the same time. I must have been writing my comment while you hit "enter". lol

Comment: The differences to call a normal version and a o-version was for sanitation purposes. Not to be retarded, I was making sure that the url sanatized version != to the regular, obviously that wasn't added yet....

Comment: @RainbowdashTM Did you not test this on a smaller scale? That's what I do. Once I have something that I know for a fact works, I then build on it/add on after. I for one can't make "heads or tails" ouf of this. Maybe [**YCS's answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19737083/1415724) below will help you out.

Comment: @Fred-ii

I did actually, let me try lowering what is inputted into the database in one go? Could that be the problem? It was working before. Hm.

Comment: @RainbowdashTM It's easier to gradually add then it is to troubleshoot "after the fact". Has YCS's answer helped, have you tried it? It may be an easier and more maintainable method.

Comment: Found the issue. Remember to always check the table names. Thanks YCS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes the only code you need. 
Insert variables may not reflect the actual data - I didn't bother to investigate, but only to show you that you don't need to assign and re-assign and then re-reassign your input variables five times in a row. Everything that goes straight from the browser, can be bound as is.

```
// setting error reporting for php and mysqli
// on a live site display errors have to be set to 0
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

//connect
$username = "=";
$password = "m=";
$host = "=rce.com";
$dbname = "=";
$con = mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$dbname);

//insert
$query = "INSERT INTO project
          (company,published,user,contacturl,model,serialalgo,members,method,warn) 
          VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $con->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("sssssssss",
    $_POST['company'],
    $_POST['companyproduct'],
    $_POST['curl'],
    $_POST['mem'],
    $_POST['model'],
    $_POST['serialalgo'],
    $_POST['meth'],
    $_POST['warn']
);
$stmt->execute();
```